# Baisc Restful Webservice Project 404 Not Found

Tags: java, web-services, rest, maven, restful-url

I am learning Restful webservices using jax RS (jersey) Implementation. I have created a sample maven project using jersery quick start web app.
code:

**index.jsp**

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>Jersey RESTful Web Application!</h2>
<p><a href="webapi/myresource">Jersey resource</a>
<p>Visit <a href="http://jersey.java.net">Project Jersey website</a>
for more information on Jersey!
```

**MyResource.java**

```
 package org.restful.sumanth.RestfulSumanth;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

/**
 * Root resource (exposed at "myresource" path)
 */
@Path("myresource")
public class MyResource {

/**
 * Method handling HTTP GET requests. The returned object will be sent
 * to the client as "text/plain" media type.
 *
 * @return String that will be returned as a text/plain response.
 */
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getIt() {
    return "Got it!";
}
}
```

**WEB.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
     see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation    /latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>org.restful.sumanth.RestfulSumanth</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

When i run the project i have the output:

```
Jersey RESTful Web Application!

[Jersey resource][1]

Visit [Project Jersey website][2] for more information on Jersey! 


  [1]: http://webapi/myresource
  [2]: https://jersey.java.net/
```

When i click on Jersey Resource link it is giving 404 even though i have resource. Can some please explain why myresource is not able to find when requested?

Comment: could you add your maven dependencies?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [404 error with Jersey REST Service on Tomcat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29315062/404-error-with-jersey-rest-service-on-tomcat)

Comment: What version of Tomcat are you using? I had this issue and after upgrading to version 10 it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the answer from another stackoverflow post: [404 error with Jersey REST Service on Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29315062/404-error-with-jersey-rest-service-on-tomcat)

I have replaced the below dependency which made it work :
**from**

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
<version>2.17</version>
</dependency>
```